# how to decompile a .apk without errors?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, decompiler, apktool

I tried the apktool, and even the online version, http://www.decompileandroid.com/
But still can't get something that works in eclipse.

I want to decompile an app called bucket drops, which was made as part of an android course. I want to look at the source code and tweak it.

When I tried decompiling the .apk file it lacked the .classpath and .project files, so I made a new project in eclipse and copied the source code into it, but for some reason eclipse shows that the app is buggy!

What do I do?

Comment: Decompiled java code doesn't keep the class names, does it?

Comment: You should also switch to Android Studio because as of 2016 eclipse isn't supported anymore for Android development

Answer (score 0):

How-To: Decompile/Recompile apk's with ApkTool

---

Requirements:

ApkTool
Java JDK/JRE 32 bit 
Basic Cmd/terminal knowledge

---

Download ApkTool here

ApkTool.zip

first you need to extract that zip folder to anywhere you choose, preferably on root of c/drive ie: C:/android/apktool extracting the files to 'apktool' folder

Now place the STOCK framework-res.apk & whatever other apk's you would like to modify into the 'apktool' folder

---

Getting to CMD directory

Open up a Cmd Prompt (terminal) and get to the 'apktool' directory ie:

Your cmd will probly look like this..

C:\users\yourname>

so type in

cd.. (yes include the '..' and press enter after you type each command)

this will get you to back directory so now you will see

C:\users>

so type again

cd..

you should now see this:

C:>

now type in:

cd 'apktoo'l/'directory'

for me it looks like:

cd android/apktool

now you should see:

C:/android/apktool>

and you are in the apktool directory :D

### Click to expand...

Installing Framework

Now that you are in directory we need to install the device's framework to your system for it to compile correctly so type this:

apktool if framework-res.apk

this will install the devices framework to your system (need to do this)

---

Decompiling

now to decompile the apk you want to edit.. type this:

apktool d framework-res.apk framework1

or

apktool d music.apk music

music.apk is the apk your decompiling
music is the folder you're creating for the decompiled apk

now make your edits :D DO NOT Change/Edit ANY PNG's

---

Recompiling/Finished Product

now to recompile your new apk type this:

apktool b music music-new.apk

or

apktool b framework1 framework-res-new.apk

framework1 is the folder with your edited files
framework-res-new.apk is your new apk file :D

Now we are NOT done... we cannot use the new apk's... we have to take what we did and add it back to the original apk file to keep proper signature :D

use something like 7zip, take the 'resources.arcs' file and any other xml files you edited out of the "-new" apk and copy them into Original apk

### now the apk is ready to flash with your new changes :D :D

Hope this helped some of you new themers out there!!!

Source: [AndroidForums](http://androidforums.com/threads/guide-how-to-properly-decompile-and-recompile-apks-with-apktool.520917/)

Comment: Please consider that to add essential part of the answer , but not as a link!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning

Comment: This doesn't address importing the decompiled code into an IDE

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleague has written a ruby Gem to address this problem, It can decompile an Apk and open it's code in a friendly GUI.
[apkToJava](http://www.singhajit.com/convert-apk-file-to-java-code/) is the gem name. you should try it once.

It's an easy to use tool which just take two to three commands to get an Apk decompiled.

```
gem install apkToJava
apkToJava setup
apkToJava /path/to/apk/file.apk
```

As of now its support only two operating systems **Mac OS** and **Linux**.

Comment: How does this solve the problem? The Ruby code is essentially a wrapper around dex2jar and jadx, both can be used as command line utilities rather than needing ruby